# How to generate a custom link in Wagtail using Wagtail hooks

Tags: django, view, wagtail

So I want to add a extra link in the Wagtail admin. I am following the docs ([Register Admin Menu Item Hook](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item)) and using this hook to contruct a new menu item.

They use this hook for adding menu items:

```py
@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_edit_menu_item():
    return MenuItem('Edit profile', 'edit_link', classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse', order=10000)
```

This should become a link which starts editing a page that is owned by the current logged in user. In a template I use this code to create a direct link to edit the profile of a user:

```
{% with request.user.owned_pages.all as pages %}
   {% if pages.exists %}
      {% for p in pages %}
         {% if p.get_parent.id == 17 %}
         <a class="list-group-item" href="/dashboard/pages/{{ p.id }}/edit/"><i class="fe-icon-edit mr-1 text-muted"></i>Edit profile</a>
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

This is working just fine, it links directly to the page that it is supposed to link to. However how do I implement a condition like this where I generate the menu link based on the current logged in user?

I would think something like:

```py
if request.user.owned_pages.exists():
   for p in request.user.owned_pages.all():
      if p.get_parent.id == 17:
         edit_link = "/dashboard/pages/" + p.id + "/edit/"
```

But how can I implement something like this into the Wagtail menu hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default implementation of `MenuItem`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/af4f27aa3ec6d704a9a2f71ea81b0a3572502433/wagtail/admin/menu.py#L10) assumes that the URL will be constant over all page requests, meaning that we can pass that fixed URL to the `MenuItem` constructor inside the `register_admin_menu_item` hook (that runs on server startup).

In your case, this isn't true, so you'll need to define a custom subclass of `MenuItem`. If you look at the code for `MenuItem`, you'll see that it implements a `get_context(self, request)` method to gather all the template variables it needs to render the menu item, including `url`. You can override this method to set a dynamic URL in place of the fixed one:

```
class EditProfileMenuItem(MenuItem):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        edit_link = None
        if request.user.owned_pages.exists():
           for p in request.user.owned_pages.all():
              if p.get_parent().id == 17:
                 edit_link = "/dashboard/pages/" + p.id + "/edit/"

        if edit_link:
            context['url'] = edit_link

        return context
```

You can then use this subclass in the `register_admin_menu_item` hook, in place of `MenuItem`:

```
@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_edit_menu_item():
    return EditProfileMenuItem('Edit profile', 'edit_link', classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse', order=10000)
```

(Depending on your requirements you may want to override the `is_shown` method too, so that the menu item is hidden from those users who don't have a profile.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, works like a charm. The only thing to add is that I forgot in my pseudo code that `p.id` returns an integer so it should be `str(p.id)`